# Question on proving validity in predicate logic

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

Using the proof rules of predicate logic prove the validity of the following sequent:

$$ \forall X  \exists Y(P(X)\lor Q(Y))\vdash \exists Y \forall X(P(X)\lor Q(Y)) $$

I have been trying to prove this for quite a long time but nothing at all seems to work.Any guidelines on how to go about it would really help. Thanks.

The Question is taken from Exercise 2.3 Q9(f) from the book Logic in computer science by Michael Huth and Mark Ryan.

Comment: Hint: I don't know the precise system of logic in your book, but it may help if I explain why this is valid. If $\exists Y\,Q(Y)$ is valid, then the right-hand side of the sequent is already valid using any witness for $\exists Y\,Q(Y)$ as a witness. If not then, $\forall Y\lnot(Q(Y))$ is valid, but then the left-hand side of the sequent is equivalent to $\forall X\,P(X)$, which means the right-hand side of the sequent follows from the left-hand side using any $Y$ as a witness. So the structure of the proof is a case analysis on $\exists Y\,Q(Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your book and the system it uses seems to be the same as the Fitch system I like to use.  The key to this proof is to set it up as a Proof by Contradiction:

[image]